# Error while running expect script in Java

Tags: java, expect

I am running an expect script from java. But i am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1010)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:615)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:483)
        at ExpectInJava.main(ExpectInJava.java:24)
```

I am able to run the expect script manually and it works fine.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class ExpectInJava {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[]params = new String[] {
                "/runScp.expect",
                "/runScp.expect",
                "root@10.21.21.21:/tmp",
                null,
                ""+22,
                ""+600,
                ""+2405,
                ""+"/var/db/host/privatekeys/"+"newsshcred"
                };

        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(params);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("e"+e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `null` from the string array?

Comment: I would assume the null in your params Array causes the NPE. Maybe try "null" or ""?

Comment: It worked like magic,but Null is one of the parameters to the Script> why is it that when done manually it works and not within Java ?
Thanks McDowell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `null` from array

```
String[]params = new String[] {
        "/runScp.expect",
        "/runScp.expect",
        "root@10.21.21.21:/tmp",
        "",
        ""+22,
        ""+600,
        ""+2405,
        ""+"/var/db/host/privatekeys/"+"newsshcred"
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

Take alook at the [documentation](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Runtime.java.html) of the exec method:

```
482       public Process exec(String cmdarray[]) throws IOException {
483           return exec(cmdarray, null, null);
484       }
```

It states when such an Exception is thrown:

```
472        * @throws  NullPointerException
473        *          If <code>cmdarray</code> is <code>null</code>,
474        *          or one of the elements of <code>cmdarray</code> is <code>null</code>
475        *
```

Read the Line **474**

Answer (score 1):

What is that `null` doing there in the `params` array? While `ProcessBuilder` can take an array of strings, they'd better be real strings and not `null` because they're going to be passed as arguments to the subprocess, and the underlying API for that doesn't like `null` at all. (Also, Expect *really* doesn't handle nulls.)